# facebook graph api -- how to un-invite more than one friends from event?

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api

There is only one friend can be un-invited from event in the [document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) one time.

I want to un-invite more than one friend - how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can issue `DELETE` request to [`invited`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#invited) connection of [`event`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) object in Graph API (or GET with `method=delete`):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/invited?users=uid1,uid2,uid3&method=delete
```